# A Blessing of Unicorns?

Tags: fantasy-genre, unicorns, penny-arcade

According to [Penny Arcade](http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2013/10/21), A group of Unicorns is called "A Blessing Of Unicorns"

Where was that stated? Why was it really called a blessing? 
..was Gabe spot on?

Comment: If you do a search for 'group of unicorns', you'll find many references that do verify they're called a Blessing.  However, none of the hits (I looked at the first 50) give any indication of how that term originated.

Comment: re: [This](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35722982#35722982) - [Sleepers?](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/292740.Sleepers).

Comment: @Valorum fantastic, thank you. This is the book

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blessing) has it listed and cites three examples (two of which are online articles and all of which are relatively recent), but it's not in [this list](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/what-do-you-call-a-group-of) from the Oxford dictionaries. So it seems to be not completely made up, but probably a bit of a neologism. Whether you consider it "real" depends on your criteria for legitimacy.

Note that such [collective nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_nouns) are often more a matter of linguistic playfulness than serious taxonomy:

> Even in their original context of medieval venery, the terms were of the nature of kennings, intended as a mark of erudition of the gentlemen able to use them correctly rather than for practical communication. The popularity of these terms in the early modern and modern period has resulted in the addition of numerous light-hearted, humorous or "facetious" collective nouns.

Comment: very informative, thanks.